# Prevent multiple login CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, multiple-login

I have finished the CakePHP3 [Blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html). Now I want to prevent users from multiple login on same computer. I mean, after having logged in, the user has to log out in order to access the log in action again. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the exact same issue here's how I fixed it. In your AppController, add this to your initialize function:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
    ]);
```

This basically forces the user to log-in before anything else.

And in the controller that handles the login I added this:

```
if($this->Auth->user()){
        $this->Flash->error(__('You are already logged in!'));
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'index']);
    }
```

This checks if there is already a user logged in and, if so, is redirected to the home page.

Comment: Man, I remember I did try the Auth->user() and it didn't work. But after seeing your answer, I tried again and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why but $this->Auth->user() doesn't work in logout function as I try to prevent non logged in user from logging out. It seems like this function doesn't work in some function(as I encountered before)

Comment: Here's the function I use for logging out:
public function logout(){
  $this->Flash->success(__('You are logged out.'));
  return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
 }

Answer (score -1):

`AuthComponent::identify()`

You need to manually call `$this->Auth->identify()` to identify the user using credentials provided in request. Then use `$this->Auth->setUser()` to log the user in, i.e., save user info to session. When authenticating users, attached authentication objects are checked in the order they are attached. Once one of the objects can identify the user, no other objects are checked. A sample login function for working with a login form could look like:

```
public function login()
{
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $user = $this->Auth->identify();
    if ($user) {
        $this->Auth->setUser($user);
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'), [
            'key' => 'auth'
        ]);
    }
}
}
```

The above code will attempt to first identify a user by using the POST data. If successful we set the user info to the session so that it persists across requests and then redirect to either the last page they were visiting or a URL specified in the loginRedirect config. If the login is unsuccessful, a flash message is set.

Refer this [Authentication Session](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html)

Comment: Your solution is almost the same with login function from the Blog tutorial (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout). And it doesn't prevent multiple logins also. I want to prevent a person who logged in on a computer from logging in again on the same computer. The user has to log out first before trying to log in again.

Comment: We need to persist the data in session or Cookie to do it. When we login we need to persist the info in session or cookie until the logout is clicked. Better is go with cookie component encrypted. Refer [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/cookie.html).
Note : you have to check the value on each page from the cookie. if the value is not there, it has to get redirected to login page.